# How config Eclipse/Android plugin to ignore desktop.ini files?

Tags: android, eclipse

The Eclipse and Android Tools plugin combination always fails to build whenever there's a desktop.ini file in one of the project directories (e.g. res/values/desktop.ini).

I would like Eclipse and/or the Android Tools plugin to ignore desktop.ini files. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand this comment.

Comment: I carefully check every single answer. An answer that answers my question will be accepted immediately. An answer that doesn't answer my question will be ignored because if I do accept this wrong or misleading answer it might confuse other readers here. So to ask again, can I configure Eclipse and or Android AAPT to ignore deskop.ini files. It's funny that Google Drive doesn't work with Google Android AAPT ...

Answer (score 5):

Just figured this out... was having google drive issues as well. To fix it:

1. Go to "Project->Properties->Resource Filters" (in Eclipse)
2. Select 'Add'
3. Set 'Filter type' to 'Exclude all', set 'Applies to' to 'Files', check the box labeled 'All children (recursive)', and make the rule so Name matches '*.ini' or 'desktop.ini'.

And that should do it.

Comment: I just did remove my acceptance mark. It is true that Eclipse doesn't show these files any longer - but I still do get errors. Sorry.

Comment: That's a shame. I hope other people that run into this problem can still find my answer. Took me a while to figure out and it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: It's not always. Seems that the res folders produce the errors - not the src folders. What's very interesting: With your suggested setting I can't see the desktop.ini file in the failing res folder. I have to use my TotalCommander to remove it from the filesystem, refresh (F5) the folder within Eclipse and the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put `desktop.ini` to resource folder. ADT will always fail if you put there anything that is not supported.

Comment: I do not put these files in there - it's Google Drive that puts them into all directories. My development environment is completely hosted on Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio, there is no way, currently, to exclude files from the build (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25184988/3499115). So, you just have to search for all the desktop.ini files in the Application/src/main/res and Application/build folders and delete them.