# Every folder in my android project has a desktop.ini file

Tags: android, eclipse

I was working on my android project, which is stored on Google Drive, and I started getting a bunch of errors. When I looked, it looked like every folder in my project had a desktop.ini file added to it. I figured that I would just go into Google Drive and delete them all but if I search for desktop.ini it returns no results in Windows Explorer. I've tried deleting them through Eclipse but it seems like when I delete one, three more take it's place. I'm not sure what's going on or how to fix this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See if you can set the build system to ignore them somehow.

Comment: desktop.ini is a hidden windows file that holds settings specific to your windows folder.  Google Drive probably uploads everything whether it is hidden or not.  I think the more important questions are what is the errors you are getting.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/31350668/3499115

Answer (score 0):

if you click on the package or class and then click on the top bar "Project", an option page should open. navigate to:Resource - Recourse filters. click on add filters. Filter type: exclude all. Applies to files (all children). type desktop.ini in the box and click ok.